# How to handle long time processing request

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, api, rest

I have a spring boot rest API deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and I am trying to upload pictures through it.

This is what I did : Upload a zip file through a file input from the browser, get the zip file on the server, go through all the files and upload each one on AWS S3.

It works fine but I ran into a problem: When I try to upload lots of pictures, I get an HTTP error (504 Gateway Timeout). I found out this is because the server takes too much time to respond, and I am trying to figure how to set a higher timeout for the requests (didn't find yet).
But in the mean time I am asking myself if it is the best solution.

Wouldn't it be better to end the request directly after receiving the zip file, make the uploads to S3 and after that notify the user that the uploads are done ? Is there even a way to do that ? Is there a good practice for this ? (operation that takes lots of time to process).

I know how to do the process asynchronously but I would really like to know how to notify the user after it completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't it be better to end the request directly after receiving the zip file, make the uploads to S3 and after that notify the user that the uploads are done ?

Yes, **asynchronous processing** of the uploaded images in the zip file would be better.

> Is there even a way to do that ? Is there a good practice for this ? (operation that takes lots of time to process).

Yes there is a better way. To keep everything within EB, you could look at [Elastic Beanstalk worker environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html). The worker environment is ideal for processing your images.

In this solution, your web based environment would store the images uploaded in S3 and submit it names along with other identifying information to an **SQS queue**. The queue is an entry point for the worker environment.

Your workers would process the images from the queue **independently from the web environment**. In the meantime, the web environment would have to check for the results and notify your users once the images get processed.

The EB also supports [linking different environments](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-cfg-links.html). Thus you could establish a link between web and worker environments for easier integration.

Comment: Thanks ! I am new to aws, I will do some research on worker environment and SQS queue.
"the web environment would have to check for the results and notify your users once the images get processed" -> How to notify the user ?

Comment: @Roronoa_D._Law This is application specific and there are many ways of doing this. In the simplest case, after submitting the zip file, your website would be pooling for results status using javascript. If this is really long processing, the worker could send email to the end user that images are ready. So it really depends on your use-case.